# ASP.NET - How to prevent user from editing asp:CheckBox using inspect?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, webforms, web-inspector

I have CheckBox that is enabled and disabled from server side, but when User edit it in inspect He can alter data even if it is disabled. Is there way how to prevent it like adding readonly attribute on asp:TextBox?

Here is my CheckBox html sample:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest" runat="server" />
```

And here is behind code:

```
        cbTest.Enabled = false;
        //cbTest.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
        //cbTest.Attributes.Add("onclick", "event.preventDefault();");
```

I have tried adding onclick atributes, but with no success.

Here is script for preventDefault():

```
        window.onload = function () {

        $('.readonly:checkbox').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    }
```

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Changes on Client-side are not passed back to controls that have been set `Enabled = false` on server side. Why is this a issue?

Comment: Because when User check/uncheck that disabled checkbox He can pass it on the server. Try It and see.

Comment: Seems it is indeed working as you described. If the user must never be able to change these values you have to validate this on serverside. Meaning you set the checkboxes disabled for the user depending on a condition. Use same condiition to read the checkboxes. Anything coming from clientside can be potentially modified.

Comment: Yes that is definitely solution, but when I have an application with about 100K controls with that problem, I should hire a monkey to changed it. Isn't there a more general solution?